# DataBinding a 2nd degree subclass

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, windows-store-apps

I need help in binding data especially if the root datasource object has many subclasses and those subclasses has a subclass too. Here is my DataModel:

```
public class NowShowingMovies
{
  public ObservableCollection<Movie> MovieCollection { get; set; }
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public string Total{ get; set; }
}
public class Movie
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Title {get;set}
  public UserRating Rating {get;set;}
}
public class UserRating
{
  public string UserRatingURL {get;set;}
}
```

And my XAML code is:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding MovieCollection}"
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Border Background="White">
                   <TexBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
             <Grid Background="Black" Margin="0,0,0,0" Opacity="0.75" x:Name="grid_rating"/>
                                <Image Source ="{Binding Path=MovieCollection.Rating.UserRatingURL}" />
             </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
 </GridView.ItemTemplate>
 </GridView>
```

Problem is I can't make it work. UserRatingURL is not showing. I even changed it to

```
<Image Source ="{Binding Path=MovieCollection[0].Rating.UserRatingURL}" />
```

and still, no luck. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove MovieCollection in your path.

Image Source ="{Binding Path=Rating.UserRatingURL}"